# How to use an PDF viewer in Flex mobile

Tags: android, apache-flex, pdf, air, flash-builder

I am developing a mobile application in Flex in Adobe Flash buillder 4.6 that will run on Android and iOS.

I need a way to view PDF files stored in the application storage directory. Searched in several forums and none of the suggestions worked for me.

In iOS'm using a StageWebView but Android still have not found a working solution.

Can be used ANE or not.
It needs to work offline, so I can not use google docs as a proxy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what's wrong with StageWebView on Android platform?

Comment: This does not work to view PDF on Android.
When I load the file on StageWebView the view is blank.

Must be the same happens when I try to view the pdf by Android browser, it downloads rather than viewing the file.

My code is:
`var pdf:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(file);
    stageWebView.loadURL("file:" + pdf.nativePath);
`

Comment: Yea, looks like a problem. Same question and answers here btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184927/how-open-pdf-in-air-for-android-black-berry . So if GPU rendering still doesn't help, then good look with ANE solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

I think I'll have to use even the ANE.

I was trying to escape it. But while the Adobe does not solve this problem natively on mobile air. We'll have to use tricks not so beautiful.

Comment: Share your experience after that!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved as was mentioned earlier.
Continued using webview in iOS and a ANE made a call to the Android application registered to open PDF.

Sorry for delay in giving feedback.

Thans for all